# Center Spinner on user center screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make my firstspinner:

```
''''
#spinner-bg-loading{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #1F3A51;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 10000;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#spinner-bg {
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

<div id="spinner-bg">
  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="spinner-borderX" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only" id="spinner-bg-loading"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

''''
```

It's work fine, but i need small change.

The spinner currently displays 25% from the top. When I am at the bottom of the long page, the spinner is invisible (because it is at the top).

I need show it on user center screen, not to center website.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered `position: fixed`? ([MDN Position documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))

Comment: I can't see anything. It's a blank page. Did you miss anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 2):

The height of the containing element should be `100vh`, not `100vw`.

Then, you can set the `top` and `left` of the spinner itself to `50%` and translate it back by `-50%` to get the actual center.

```css
#spinner-bg-loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  /* other CSS properties... */
}
#spinner-bg {
  height: 100vh;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: See the code working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7d4psoua/).

Answer (score 1):

You set the `spinner_bg height` to `100vw`, it should be `100vh`,  and also change the spinner top to `50%`

Try This:

```
''''

#spinner-bg-loading{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #1F3A51;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 10000;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#spinner-bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}


<div id="spinner-bg">
  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="spinner-borderX" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only" id="spinner-bg-loading"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''
```

here's a working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wsnrfb6g/2/

Comment: I've edited my answer to match you example syntax. but here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/wsnrfb6g/2/